# Generating a static website from a set of content data (possibly with webgen, webby or a similar toolkit)

Tags: html, ruby, webby

My company (an engineering firm) is looking to redesign their website with some dynamic content.  We have a nice portfolio of projects that we'd like to present on our site by category.

To elaborate, I'd like to have a "Projects Category" menu, where you can choose a sub-project category (such as churches, schools, etc) which links to a page with images of all projects which have been tagged with that category attribute.  Clicking on an image would then take you to a detailed page for that project.

I have done a good bit of asp and jsp page development, but I've always worked on the front end in an enterprise environment - I've never built a production site from the back end.  The advice I've gotten so far is that a full-blown CMS solution would be somewhat overkill, as we won't have a large hit count, and we'll be displaying a few hundred projects at most.

One big-picture choice I appear to have - whether to dynamically generate the pages (with asp or jsp) or to use a tool to generate a set of static html pages.  The tool would build the menus, project summary pages, and individual project pages based on a set of data I could provide (in the form of a database or text file.)

I'm leaning towards trying to use a tool like webgen or webby to statically generate the site due to our current web hosting situation.  Any thoughts on which approach is more appropriate?  Is webgen or webby capable of doing what I am trying to do?  Or can anyone recommend other web authoring tools better equipped to accomplish this?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186290/best-static-website-generator

Comment: Noted. It looks like nanoc might do what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965838/best-way-to-create-a-blog-with-static-pages-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been told that webgen can't do what I'm trying to do (without some manual coding extensions myself) but that nanoc can.
http://nanoc.stoneship.org/

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll may be worth a look.

Refer: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/wiki/

Answer (score 1):

You could always use Template Toolkit :)