# Best way to create a blog with static pages in Ruby

Tags: ruby, web, blogs

I just visited the [Static Website Generation](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/static_website_generation.html) on [Ruby toolbox](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) and I don't know which of applications listed there is best suited for a little blog engine. Basically I need:

- an index page with 1..5 of latest articles with shortened content;
- possibility to add few main pages and a menu to access them (breadcrumb optional);
- show articles
- show/search  archives
- commenting system - Disqus Ok
- tag-list cloud - optional
- Look&Feel via layout

**Important** all content will be  translated in 3 languages!
I can host on my own server, so side processing is possible.

**Update:**

First I'll try `nanoc` => [blog's source on github](http://github.com/kfl62/blog-kfl62.trst.ro)

Comment: My friend Google :) told me to read [this (helpful info)](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=998411)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/) worth a try it has everything you specified, even if is not the best ranked on ruby toolbox  its actively developed and highly customizable.
`nanoc is a tool that runs on your local computer and compiles documents written in formats such as Markdown, Textile, Haml… into a static web site consisting of simple HTML files, ready for uploading to any web server.`
and thats true :) I use it for a while not specially for a blog, but it has also helpers for that...

Comment: Thanks for tip I'll check out the helpers

Answer (score 4):

check out [jekyll](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), it should work well for this.

Comment: I checked out. I can't decide (yet): I hate liquid and even there are some haml templating forks ... Don't know maybe ...

Answer (score 2):

Try my own "serious" - apart from archive search and tag cloud, it has everything you specified, plus the basic install should take you something like 5 minutes on heroku (and maybe 10 on your own server via Rack). It also has syntax highlighting, Disqus comments, Google Analytics and other goodies.

http://github.com/colszowka/serious

`gem install serious`

Disclaimer: It does not produce static html pages you can upload to your php vhost, though. But it uses caching and is really easy to setup and works on the free plan on heroku.

Comment: Awesome! StupidFormatter is great :). As I see uses Sinatra to render pages/articles and has no option to save the renders somewhere from where man can publish them as **static pages**. I don't want to run Sinatra on server just publish a directory's content with nginx. Anyway thanks a lot +1 :)